# pandas sort values after certain column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

i have following code

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=records)
tabelle=dataframe.copy()
print(tabelle[["date","kw_search","impressions"]])
```

with following results

```
         date                 kw_search          impressions
 0      2021-02-13           takoyaki pfanne          284
 1      2021-02-13  aluguss pfanne viereckig            6
 2      2021-02-13                b0775v4vqn            8
 3      2021-02-13                  eggs pan           80
 4      2021-02-13         tamagoyaki pfanne           45
 ...           ...                       ...          ...
 13535  2021-08-18                b09575d5kh          136
 13536  2021-08-18              honigspender           62
 13537  2021-08-18               waffeleisen           44
 13538  2021-08-18     yagdanlik ve sirkelik            3
 13539  2021-08-18      bluetooth nachttisch            1
```

i want to sort by values of impression:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=records)
tabelle=dataframe.copy()
tabelle.sort_values(by=['impressions'])
print(tabelle[["date","kw_search","impressions"]])
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

but the result didnt change. it stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

got the answer
i forgot to set inplace=True
code should be:

```
tabelle.sort_values(by=['impressions'],inplace=True)
```